# Can't get to the north

Tags: far-cry-4

I've been playing Far Cry 4 for a while but have got to the point where I'm not being offered any further missions and can't progress. For the whole of south Kyrat; I've found every location and lost letter, destroyed every propaganda poster and Mask of Yalung but can't progress any further.

Is there something I need to do to get to the north? I'm assuming I need the Key to the North mission to be offered to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug introduced by one of the patches. I've discovered a couple of other references to this during searches and they follow a similar pattern: Two or three of the Shangri-La and or Reggie and Yogi missions have been done but the game stats don't register these.

There are a couple of mentions of people getting round the bug by visiting the Shangri-La mission locations but this didn't work for me. In the end I had to restart the game, losing 30+ hours of game play.

Comment: Think positive: you *gained* 30+ hours of game play. ;)